# Event Reminder time set, Off by 6 hours

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have searched for help on this issue but I am falling short of an answer. I am setting an event reminder with code. Using break points and stepping thru. I see the event time is correct. Below is how I set my reminder

```
EKEventStore *eventDB = [[[EKEventStore alloc] init]autorelease];
EKEvent *myEvent  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventDB];
NSString * eventTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",app.dealerBusinessName,serviceOrComments.text];
myEvent.title = eventTitle;




// "destinationDate" is the date I want to set the reminder for it is correct in debugger
//its format is 2011-06-03 15:45:58 +0000 which means (i would think) that the reminder
//should be set for 6/3/2011 3:45PM but its always 6 hours earlier (in this case at 9:45am

NSLog(@"value: %@",destinationDate);

    myEvent.startDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:0 sinceDate:destinationDate ]autorelease];
myEvent.endDate   = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:3600 sinceDate:myEvent.startDate]autorelease];
    myEvent.allDay = NO;

    myAlarmsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    EKAlarm *alarm1 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-3600]; // 1 Hour
    EKAlarm *alarm2 = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-86400]; // 1 Day
    [myAlarmsArray addObject:alarm1];
    [myAlarmsArray addObject:alarm2];
    myEvent.alarms = myAlarmsArray;



[myEvent setCalendar:[eventDB defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

NSError *err;

[eventDB saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err]; 

    if (err == noErr) {
        //no error, but do not show alert because we do that below.
    }
```

Now im pretty sure I can just add 21,600 to the time but is that the correct way to do it? I am not understanding how NSDate works and its driving me nuts. Can someone explain to me what the correct way to do this is? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem lately, it was really driving me nuts. You have to take your time zone into account (or the timezone your simulator/device are set to). NSDate represents always GMT time, NSCalendar the time within the time zone. So the time differences you are experiencing will exactly be the time difference between your time zone and GMT (your alarm gets triggered at 15:45 GMT).

Since I want my dates to be absolute, regardless of the time zone, I am setting all my NSCalendars to GMT - it works in my case, of course YMMV.

Comment: thanks for the help understanding this.I have setup some code that looks at the time difference between the users local time and GMT. For example it is -21000 . Then I created an integer that reverses that time difference (changes it to 21000) and uses that to offset the calendar (which sets the correct time for the local user in the calendar). Worked out well!